# Have scrollbar scrolled to the bottom without using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am currently setting a scrollbar to show as scrolled to the bottom upon page load by using this jquery code -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.mydiv').scrollTop($('.mydiv')[0].scrollHeight);
});
```

Is there a way to do this using only css? So that this scrollbar is automatically scrolled to the bottom when the user visits the page?

Comment: Why? If you always want to do this, why not re-order the content? The convention (books, comics, web pages) is we read top to bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this without javascript by using anchors in the URL and in the document, with you placing the target anchor at the bottom of the page. Though this is not really very elegant.

Comment: Perfectly elegant! I was about to suggest this.

Comment: @ColonelPanic I just meant it might not be elegant if they want clean URL's or want this to happen on say a site homepage where you don;t have control over how links to the page are made.

Answer (score 0):

There is browser based extension that can help you with that.
Different browsers use different extensions:
Chrome, Safari: WebKit, IE: Trident, FF: Gecko.
Each one can have different ways to do that.
I don't know specific features of webkits, but try to google for example

::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece:start

I know it is not a straigtforward answer, but I hope it will help you in your research.

Comment: These pseudo elements are for styling the scrollbar, not for scrolling to bottom!